# nth-of-type selecting wrong element

Tags: html, css

Could someone on here explain to me why the pseudo selector 3n+4 on my li.prod-shown class is selecting not the 4th, 7th, 10th, 13th, 16th, 19th.. and so on, but the 4th, 6th, 11th, 13th and 16th as shown in the codepen below, when there are additional li-s inserted into the fold.

I'm not good at explaining so best if you took a look at the pen. :)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbOEMY

```
li.prod-shown:nth-of-type(3n+4) {  
    background: tomato;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be helpful https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Answer (score 1):

Nth-of-type selects the [nth element with a particular tag name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type), not with a particular class. Therefore your elements of class `quickview` are also getting selected, which is throwing your numbering off.